# How to use a csv file with oldvalue:newvalue to replace string inside files and filenames

Tags: csv, rename

We have a large number of rules files that carry one of >200 phonenumbers in their filename and/or reference the phonenumber in the file itself.
Now most of these phonenumbers need to be changed so we have an input csv file that has a column for the old phonenumber and a column for the phonenumber.
As an additional complication, there are also comments inside the files that contain the phonenumber, but with spaces in the right places, e.g. 0800 123 456.
The phonenumbers in the csv file are also with the spaces like in the comments.

What we want to achieve is to write a (Shell) Script that reads the csv file and replaces all occurences of the old phonenumber inside the files (with and without spaces) with the new phonenumber (again with spaces in the comments and without spaces in the other places).
Additionally, if a file is found that has the phonenumber in the filename, it should be renamed.

I'm sure this can be done with sed and similar tools but I'm lacking the experience with sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution myself. It's not beautiful and far from being efficient but it does the job.
The preconditions are an input file with lines in the following format:

```
<old string>;<new string>
```

The "old string" in my case is a phone number in the format

```
012 345 67 89
```

The reason for having the number with whitespace is that we have it in the comment in each file so we need to replace both types.

Here's my BASH Script assuming you want to scan all files in the subdirectory "src" and your input file is named "bns.csv":

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  OLD=`echo $line | awk -F\; '{print $1}'`
  ## Remove leading and trailing spaces
  OLDTRIM="$(echo -e "${OLD}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
  NEW="$(echo $line | awk -F\; '{print $2}')"
  NEWTRIM="$(echo -e "${NEW}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
  # Remove all spaces
  OLDPURE="$(echo -e "${OLD}" | tr -d '[[:space:]]')"
  NEWPURE="$(echo -e "${NEW}" | tr -d '[[:space:]]')"

  # Rename files first
  find src -exec rename ${OLDPURE} ${NEWPURE} {} \;

  #Find and replace both versions inside file
  find src -type f | while read file
  do
    sed -i "s/${OLDTRIM}/${NEWTRIM}/g" $file
    sed -i "s/${OLDPURE}/${NEWPURE}/g" $file
  done
done <bns.csv
```

Any optimization hints are welcome.